# Unable to generate token for One-Drive using c# .net 6

Tags: azure, graph, azure-active-directory

I am facing issue while trying to generated token for One-Drive access. As I have requirement where user can get all the files from there One Drive using my application.

I tried below code but I am getting error.

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 33a0dd6a-6984-4c0a-8f74-6fbcd9c54301\r\nCorrelation ID: 265ca054-ab98-450c-8281-851ef6b0fdc3\r\nTimestamp: 2022-11-24 15:56:04Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2022-11-24 15:56:04Z","trace_id":"33a0dd6a-6984-4c0a-8f74-6fbcd9c54301","correlation_id":"265ca054-ab98-450c-8281-851ef6b0fdc3","suberror":"consent_required"}

Find my code that I am trying.
public async Task GetTokenAsync(string tenant, string clientId, string
clientSecret, string username, string password)
{
HttpResponseMessage resp;
string token;
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
new ("application/x-www-form-
urlencoded"));
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token/");
req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
{"grant_type", "password"},
{"client_id", clientId},
{"client_secret", clientSecret},
{"resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com/"},
{"username", username},
{"password", password}

```
            });

            resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
            string content = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonObj = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(content);
            token = jsonObj["access_token"];
        }
        return token;
    }
```

Nothing

Comment: Code: notAllowed Message: You do not have access to create this personal site or you do not have a valid license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if you have not consented **Admin Consent to the API Permissions** you have granted like below:

[image]

To resolve the error, I created the **Azure AD Application and granted Admin consent to the API Permissions**:

[image]

To generate the access token, I used to the below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/token

grant_type:password
client_id:53f9d6e0-f9e8-4620-9e45-XXXXX
client_secret:Msd8Q~q~-2gb4sooQVGDIQQAI92gXXXXX
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com/
username:username
password:Password
```

**I am able to generate the access token successfully as below:**

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, try updating the below settings in Azure Enterprise Application like below:

*Go to Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> User settings -> Consent and permissions*

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can Grant admin consent by using below Endpoint, Login as Admin and **Accept**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

Comment: I am verifying the solution. Once it tested from my end , I will update. Your response is highly appreciable.

Comment: Code: notAllowed Message: You do not have access to create this personal site or you do not have a valid license

Comment: Hi , I tried same way but getting error after generating token.     
   Code: notAllowed Message: You do not have access to create this personal site or you do not have a valid license.

Comment: Could you confirm what licenses do you have currently?

Comment: license for what?

Comment: Which license, you are asking. As for development purpose i am using  VS2022 (Professional) and for Azure "Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription – MPN" subscription using.

Comment: Could you check that is office365 license assigned like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/uoPOBmT.png)

Comment: I am able to generate a token as above mentioned from postman. but getting error Code: notAllowed Message: You do not have access to create this personal site or you do not have a valid license.

Comment: Hi Rukmini, sorry for that,  Could you let me know where exactly I need to  check that is office365 license assigned like you mentioned.

Comment: In the Azure Portal -> Licenses -> All products

Comment: Hi Rukmini, I verified in my "Azure Portal -> Licenses -> All products"   
 I am not able to see Office365 in my portal. Could you please confirm that could be one reason. Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Sure , I will do that but first let me verify. Highly appreciation for you help and support.